# Inverse CDF of non-builtin probability distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, inverse

I'm trying to get the inverse CDF of the [Raised Cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raised_cosine_distribution) probability distribution function.

It has parameters $\mu$ and $s$, support $x \in [\mu - s, \mu + s]$,

PDF `1/(2 s) (1 + Cos[((x - μ)/s) π])`

and CDF `1/2 (1 + (x - μ)/s + 1/π Sin[((x - μ)/s) π])`

How can I compute its analytic inverse CDF?

---

I tried the `ProbabilityDistribution[]` construct like

```
RaisedCosineDistribution = ProbabilityDistribution[
  1/(2 s) (1 + Cos[((x - μ)/s) π]), {x, μ - s, μ + 
    s}]
```

but then taking `CDF[RaisedCosineDistribution]` didn't even give me the CDF presented above.

I'm pretty sure I am doing something in the wrong way, but don't know what.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Clear[RaisedCosineDistribution]
```

As with built-in distributions, you need to include the parameters in the distribution definition, and the constraints on the parameters as `Assumptions` in the `ProbabilityDistribution`

```
RaisedCosineDistribution[μ_, s_] =
  ProbabilityDistribution[
    1/(2 s) (1 + Cos[((x - μ)/s) π]), {x, μ - s, μ + s},
    Assumptions -> {Element[μ, Reals], s > 0}] // Simplify;
```

These `Assumptions` are then available to other related built-in functions through `DistributionParameterAssumptions`

```
DistributionParameterAssumptions[RaisedCosineDistribution[μ, s]]
```

[image]

```
PDF[RaisedCosineDistribution[μ, s], x]
```

[image]

Verifying that this is equivalent to your input

```
Assuming[{s > 0 && s + μ > x && s + x > μ}, 
 PDF[RaisedCosineDistribution[μ, s], x] == 
   1/(2 s) (1 + Cos[((x - μ)/s) π]) // Simplify]

(*  True  *)
```

The `Assumptions` are used by `CDF`

```
CDF[RaisedCosineDistribution[μ, s], x] // Simplify
```

[image]

Verifying that this is equivalent to your expected result

```
Assuming[{s > 0 && s + μ > x && s + x > μ}, 
 CDF[RaisedCosineDistribution[μ, s], x] == 
   1/2 (1 + (x - μ)/s + 1/π Sin[((x - μ)/s) π]) // Simplify]

(*  True  *)
```

The `InverseCDF` is then just used directly for numeric values of `{μ, s}` -- albeit slowly

```
Plot[InverseCDF[RaisedCosineDistribution[0, 1/2], q], {q, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This function might do the job:

```
invCDF[p_, μ_, s_] := x /. FindRoot[1/2 (1 + (x - μ)/s + 1/π Sin[((x - μ)/s) π]) == p,
  {x, μ}]
```

So the value associated with the `CDF = 0.975` would be

```
invCDF[0.975, 6, 2]
(* 7.36539 *)
```

As a check (which one should always do):

```
1/2 (1 + (x - μ)/s + 1/π Sin[((x - μ)/s) π]) /. {x -> 7.36539, μ -> 6, s -> 2}
(* 0.975 *)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would compute the analytic symbolic function, not a numerical result.

Comment: I'd like to see a symbolic function, too.  But do you think it exists?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure about that. I've seen an analytic formula for the inverse CDF of this distribution, but with implicit parameters $\mu = s = 0.5$. So it must exist.

Comment: I'm skeptical about that.  The basic equation to be solved for $x$ is $\frac{1}{2} \left(x+\frac{\sin (\pi  x)}{\pi }+1\right)=p$.  That looks pretty transcendental to me.  If you have a reference for that special case, it would be helpful to include that information in your question.